# All CSS menu when hover show submenu

Tags: css, menu

This isn't really my place of expertise, so I'm not even completely sure how this works.  I have a single menu created perfectly, which works, see [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dXrTG/).

Code:

```
<div style="display:inline-block" id="menu1outer">
  <div class="menus" style="cursor:pointer;">Menu</div>
    <a href="">
      <div id="submenus1" class="submenus" style="background-color:#1734c7;">
        Sub 1
      </div>
    <a/>
    <a href="">
      <div id="submenus1" class="submenus" style="background-color:#3151f6">
        Sub 2
      </div>
    <a/>
    <a href="">
      <div id="submenus1" class="submenus" style="background-color:#6780ff">
        Sub 3
      </div>
    <a/>
  </div>
```

And the CSS is below:

```
.menus {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #dcdcdd;
}
.submenus {
    margin-top:10px;
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: black;
}
#menu1outer:hover #submenus1 {
    display: block;
}
```

However, whenever I add a second dropdown menu, everything gets messed up.  Now whenever the first menu is hovered over, the submenus display, but the other menu gets moved.  I have already tried positioning the menus absolutely, which also messes up the inline-block div.  Sorry if this is confusing, the example helps.  Here is how it looks with the second menu with it.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HpdYB/1/)

Also, this seems a little localized, but it really isn't, it's just that I don't know how to put it into general terms because I don't know what exactly is messing up, and I'm not too good with this kind of stuff.

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is the final look of it. http://jsfiddle.net/LqNxx/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way in my oppinion is to float the "outer" `<div>` elements to left instead of positioning them with "inline-block". The HTML would look like this:

```
<div style="float:left;" id="menu1outer">
    <a href=""><div class="menus">Menu 1</div></a>
    <a href=""><div id="submenus1" class="submenus">Sub 1</div><a/>
    <a href=""><div id="submenus1" class="submenus">Sub 2</div><a/>
    <a href=""><div id="submenus1" class="submenus">Sub 3</div><a/>
</div>

<div style="margin-left:50px;float:left;" id="menu2outer">
    <a href=""><div class="menus">Menu 2</div></a>
    <a href=""><div id="submenus2" class="submenus">Sub 1</div><a/>
    <a href=""><div id="submenus2" class="submenus">Sub 2</div><a/>
    <a href=""><div id="submenus2" class="submenus">Sub 3</div><a/>
</div>
```

Or just check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EEbAM/) fiddle.

Comment: Just to be perfectionist, be sure to add a <div style="clear:both"></div> (or similair) after the last menuXouter, to have your content under your menu (like your first example) :-)

Comment: Your right, I forgot to mention that ;) Thanks for your comment